# How to count characters except double or single quotes?

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and learning C through a book.

The author of the book explains about logical operators (AND, NOT and OR) by giving the following example which counts the number of characters except the double or single quotes and period character.

**I couldn't understand how it counts the number of characters except the quotes and period character. I understand that with the AND operator both conditions should be true.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PERIOD '.'
int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    int charcount = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != PERIOD)
    {
        if (ch != '"' && ch != '\'')
            charcount++;
    }
    printf("There are %d non-quote characters.\n", charcount);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `charcount` is incremented if the character is different from `"` and if it is different from `'`.

Comment: did you understand this condition `if (ch != '"' && ch != '\'')`? Otherwise, I think it's a high-time you start with some basic C book.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to explain you the main part of the code :

```
    while ((ch = getchar()) != PERIOD)
    {
```

Here, it will check every character contained in your text, as long as the character differ from `PERIOD`, which is a dot, so it simply check all of the characters in the sentence.

```
if (ch != '"' && ch != '\'')
charcount++;
}
```

Here, it adds 1 to the `charcount` if the condition is true. For the `if` to return true, both `ch != '"'` and `ch != '\''` must be true ! The `&&` operator is a [logical AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction_.28AND.29), and for an AND to return true (1), both conditions must be equal to 1. So if the character is equal to " or ', the AND will return 0, and so we won't add 1 to the `charcount`.

Answer (score 2):

This condition `if (ch != '"' && ch != '\'')`, is checking if the entered character is `"`or `'` if not then it increments the count of characters otherwise not. If user enterd `d` or `#`, it will satisfy the condition because ASCII value of `#` is not equal to `"` or `'`, and the count will get incremented.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for each char returned by `getchar()` and stored in `ch` (from an input stream, like a keyboard or a file) it will test if it's not a double quote (`ch != '"'`) and if it's not a quote (`ch != '\''`)

`\` is an escape character, which means `'\''` is the char `'`

If it's neither of them, then it will increments the counter (`charcount++;`).

And this will go on as long as `getchar()` doesn't return a period (`(ch = getchar()) != PERIOD`)(if it does, the `PERIOD` won't be counted as the code will step out the will loop immediately).

Answer (score 0):

You can skip using continue:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define PERIOD '.'

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    int charcount = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != PERIOD)
    {
        if (ch != '"' && ch != '\''){
            continue;
        }
            charcount++;
    }
    printf("There are %d non-quote characters.\n", charcount);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> ./program 
> Michi"""LoL'''Another'"LoL.
> There are 8 non-quote characters.
> ```

Comment: The original code worked as intended, OP just didn't understand it. You can see there are 10 non-quote characters, not 8.

Comment: 3 (" " ") + 3 (' ' ') + 2 (' ") = 8 ... Can you please explain why 10 ?

Comment: "Non-quote characters". And so there are 18 non-quote characters, i don't know why i ignored characters in blue ^^'

Comment: But the OP needs this "There are 8 non-quote characters."...i got my self confused about what he intended and the print message.

Comment: He just needs someone to explaining the code he read in a book as he is new to C, he's not trying to code anything here (the code here is from the book).